# Windows handle always returning INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: c++, winapi

```
HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE, FALSE, PID);
    if (process = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Failed to open PID %d, error code %d",
            PID, GetLastError());
    }
```

I have tried this function but it always return **"Failed to open PID (number) error code 0"**. Even with only **PROCESS_VM_READ**.

When i output the value of the memory address in this code

```
ReadProcessMemory(process, (LPVOID)0x14AC1BC, &value, sizeof(DWORD), NULL);
cout << value << endl;
```

it return garbage value.

Comment: Compile with warning level 4. This would have raised [Compiler Warning C4706](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4706). This doesn't help you with your other issue: Failing to read documentation.

Comment: In the domain of Process handles, the value `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (i.e. `(HANDLE)-1`) is in fact a valid handle value. It's currently defined as the pseudo-handle that's returned by `GetCurrentProcess`. So after mistakenly assigning `process = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, you're actually reading the memory of the current process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`process = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` performs an assignment overwriting process handle value, not a comparison. Also in case of an error `OpenProcess` will return `NULL`. Rewrite check like this:

```
if(NULL == process)
```

Answer (score 9):

OpenProcess returns `NULL` on failure not `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. Also you are using `=` when you should use `==`. Code should be

```
HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE, FALSE, PID);
if (process == NULL)
{
}
```

Comment: hello john thanks for answering considering it returns NULL but why when I read the address it returns garbage value. It should return normal value like 14,254. It only returns 439483948239

Comment: @arc I wouldn't know the answer to that. Now that you've fixed your code make a new question for that.

Answer (score 5):

You mistakenly assign to the `process` variable twice. Once when you call `OpenProcess` and then again when you write

```
if (process = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
```

This assigns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` to `process` and tests whether `process` is non-zero. Which is always the case because `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is non-zero. You made the classic mistake of using `=` when you meant to use `==`. As a consequence of this you completely ignore the value returned by `OpenProcess`.

Note that `OpenProcess` indicates failure by returning `NULL`. So your code should be

```
if (process == NULL)
```